# TempDB Best Practices For Shared Storage

Tags: sql-server, best-practices, storage, tempdb

Microsoft recommends separating the SQL Data Files from the Temp Files to limit device contention but what about cases involving shared storage.  I have a shared environment where the data and temp files are located on the same mount point or LUN.  Is it best practice to separate them onto different?  Or will it make a difference from a performance standpoint?

Comment: What workload is being applied to tempdb and your user database? What IO patterns?

Answer (score 0):

There is no a definitive answer.

Anyway I suggest, if possible, to store tempdb files in different LUN. But it is worth only if tempdb is under pressure.

In my environment I use shared storage also for tempdb for performance reasons: my local disks are slower then shared storage via EMC.

Comment: So, if your temp data file's size is set to a maximum and not unlimited it still makes sense to separate them?  Also, this server has very poor performance especially during our monthly releases as a index rebuild job runs at the same time. Everything takes 3 times longer to run would storing the tempdb files in a different LUN potentionally improve performance?

Comment: Probably not so much. I suggest you to see database IO with activity monitor during your index rebuild. It will help you to see if database is stressed. Which kind of storage are you using?

Comment: I don't have alot of experience with storage and didn't set these up but they are HP Logical SCSI.

Comment: Also, I guess another thing I need to look at is if it is on its on Raid Array.  Also, if it is on its own LUN it should still get better scheduling of SCSI reservations and caching, correct?

Comment: I'm not deep expert on storage. I usually ask the person who manage storage to analyze lun stress on windows (in Linux an iostat helps). I upvoted the question to have more visibility, but I think in your specific case you will not gain a lot of performance moving temp db. It is possible to watch other directions? Partitioning or pre-elaborated data?